# Unable to INSERT into an Amazon RDS database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I setup my website on AWS.

Now, the problem is: I am able to select data from my DB but **I am not able to insert it**. But, my root is having "Insert" privileges.

I did create another user and provided the same privileges but the same problem persists.

Here is my configuration:

**mysql - "select" and "insert" privileges for "root" user.**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| Select_priv | Insert_priv |
| Y           | Y           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

**mysql - "host" and "user" details**

```
+----------------+------+
| host           | user |
| %              | root |
| 127.0.0.1      | root |
| (my ip)        | root |
| ::1            | root |
| ip-(my ip)     |      |
| ip-(my ip)     | root |
| localhost      |      |
| localhost      | root |
+----------------+------+
```

**php** - I am connecting using "username" as "root", "host" as "localhost" and "port" as 3306

**Inbound security group**

[image: inbound security groups]

**Outbound security group**

[image: outbound security groups]

[image: mysql insert query]

Comment: Hi @Amitava! What do you mean by "I am not able to insert it"? Could you please show us an example of what you are trying to do and what error message is displayed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for replying. I am using php, mysql and aws. I am not able to insert data to my database but I am able to retrieve data from my DB to the website. I tried to insert data from the website as-well as from aws cli. It's showing "1 row updated" but the DB table is empty. Don't know where it's going wrong.

Comment: Please show us an example of what you are trying to do and what error message is displayed. Unfortunately, saying "I am not able to insert data" isn't particularly useful for diagnosing your problem. The fact that you are able to connect to the database and SELECT data means that your security group settings are fine.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added "mysql insert query" image. You can see the "insert" command there and the success message. Yet, my table is empty.

Comment: The `INSERT` command you show says `Query OK`, so it is successfully inserting the data. What makes you think that the `INSERT` command did not work? (BTW, I suspect that you do not have auto-commit turned on, so the data was inserted but the transaction was rolled-back. You could test this by entering a `COMMIT;` command after the `INSERT` command.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein COMMIT after INSERT is not working. Between, I manually created a table using MySQLBench and when I am trying to view all my DB tables from AWS CLI, that particular table is missing. Also, when I am trying to connect to MySQL using "mysql -h MY_END_POINT -P 3306 -u 'MY_USER_NAME' -p", it's showing me: "ERROR 1130 (HY000) : Host is not allowed to connect to MySQL server. But I am able to connect using "mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p". '@'Michael - sqlbot I do have 'rdsadmin' user but I dont know why I am not able to view it now.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Also, I would like to add that : when I am trying to connect to MySQL using my MySQL username that I have created while creating the DB instance is showing the following error : "ERROR 1045 (28000) : Access denied for user 'MY DB INSTANCE USERNAME' @ 'localhost' (using password : YES)". And the code is: "mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u 'MY_DB_INSTANCE_USERNAME"

Comment: If you are using `mysql -h localhost`, then you are connecting to MySQL on the same machine where you typed the command, not an Amazon RDS instance.

Comment: ok. But with this - "mysql -h AMAZON_RDS_END_POINT -P 3306 -u 'MY_USER_NAME' -p", it's showing me: "ERROR 1130 (HY000) : Host is not allowed to connect to MySQL server. How to solve this error?

Comment: sorry @JohnRotenstein it was my mistake. finally solved. thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. In future, please provide as much detail as possible in your StackOverflow questions. As you've seen, the answer is often in the detail, which is why sample code, sample commands and exact error messages are very helpful.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sure.. I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Table names in insert query are case sensitive when deployed in aws RDS mysql. So, make sure to have same table names i.e. same case in insert query and in database. I hope this will work.